# Imported Database not in Cpanel

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I imported a database in phpmyadmin directly without creating a database in cpanel. I am not able to view the database in cpanel, nor can I delete it. Even the script fails to connect to it since I didn't specify a user for that database. Any help?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; it belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, it's impossible. I've tried to import a database in phpmyadmin (version 3.5.1) directly without creating a database and got this message: "#1046 - No database selected".

You are not able to do anything with database, because it just doesn't exist.